# HashMap to concurrentHashMap

Tags: java

I have a `getHashMap` method that returns `HashMap`.
I need to populate a `ConcurrentHashMap` (in `setConcurrentHashMap`) with the `HashMap`.

Is there a way to do it?

Sample code:

```
//getHashMap return a HashMap<String, String>
Map<String, String> myMap = getHashMap();
TestClass.getSingleton().setConcurrentHashMap(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> concurrentHashMap)
```

Answer (score 15):

A quick look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) shows that `ConcurrentHashMap` has a copy constructor that takes a Map as a parameter:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = getHashMap();
ConcurrentMap<String, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<> (myMap);
```

Answer (score -1):

`ConcurrentHashMap` class provides a constructor to create a `ConcurrentHashMap` from a given `Map`.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = getHashMap();
TestClass.getSingleton()
    .setConcurrentHashMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>(myMap));
```